# Fatal Error When Trying To Create A Virtual Venv For Flask?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am trying to learn FLASK. I am just following this [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_environment.htm). I have already created a venv for kivy, and all went right. But now I am learning flask and in CMD, when I pass:

```py
pip install virtualenv
```

it outputs:

```py
Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: appdirs<2,>=1.4.3 in c:\users\new\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2,>=1.9.0 in c:\users\new\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from virtualenv) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: filelock<4,>=3.0.0 in c:\users\new\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from virtualenv) (3.0.12)
Requirement already satisfied: distlib<1,>=0.3.1 in c:\users\new\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from virtualenv) (0.3.1)
```

Then I used:

```py
mkdir newproj
cd newproj
```

At last:

```py
virtualenv venv
```

And it said:

```py
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\program files\python39-32\python.exe" 
"C:\Program Files\Python39-32\Scripts\virtualenv.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I tried adding "C:\Program Files\Python39-32\Scripts\virtualenv.exe" to path. But it did not work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you try `python -m pip install virtualenv`

Comment: I don't want to install virtualenv, I already have it. But when I try to use it it giver FATAL ERROR!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as of **python 3.3**, python is shipped with its built-in virtual environment module `venv`, it's the official, the standard, the recommended and the difacto module.

refer to : https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv

so you don't even need to install any 3rd module like `virtualenv`, `pipenv` .. to create and manage your virtual environments.

1. create the root folder for your project

```
C:\> mkdir newproj
C:\> cd newproj
```

2. create the virtual environment, (as good practice and as seen in many well-known projects on github .. named it `venv`)

```
C:\newproj> py -m venv venv
```

3. activate it

```
C:\newproj> venv\Scripts\activate

(venv) C:\newproj> pip list
(venv) C:\newproj> pip install flask flask-login ..
```

4. to deactivate it

```
(venv) C:\newproj> deactivate
C:\newproj>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use :

```
python3 -m virtualenv venv
```

Comment: Glad i could help !